# Select the closest and greater value based on a given value in R

Tags: r

Here are 2 columns

```
n <- c(10,30,50,80,100,300,500,800,1000,1500,2000)   
v <- c(1.3,1,0.85,0.75,0.65,0.5,0.4,0.35,0.3,0.26,0.23)
```

one value in 'n' corresponds to one value in 'v'. Now, suppose a number x as the variable for the following function:

```
f<-function(x){1.3-(1.3-v)*(x-10)/(n-10)}
```

where 'n' is the closest but greater value toward 'x'.

Example: when x=24, then n=30, v=1, print(f)= 1.09
when x=1001, then n=1500, v=0.26, ...

I need to print all value of f with `x <- seq(from=1, to=5000)`

How to achieve this in R?

Please help. Thank you

Comment: `min(n[which( n > x)])` this will give you the closet greter value to 'x' in 'n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cut`/`findInterval` to find the closest value which is also greater than the value passed. Also note that I am passing `n` and `v` as additional arguments to the function.

```
n <- c(10,30,50,80,100,300,500,800,1000,1500,2000)   
v <- c(1.3,1,0.85,0.75,0.65,0.5,0.4,0.35,0.3,0.26,0.23)

f<- function(x, n, v) {
  i <- findInterval(x, n, left.open = TRUE) + 1
  1.3-(1.3-v[i])*(x-10)/(n[i]-10)
}

f(24, n, v)
#[1] 1.09

f(1001, n, v)
#[1] 0.6082953
```

This function is vectorised so you can pass more than 1 value to it.

```
x <- seq(from=1, to=5000)
f(x, n, v)

#[1]       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
#[8]       NaN       NaN       NaN 1.2850000 1.2700000 1.2550000 1.2400000
#[15] 1.2250000 1.2100000 1.1950000 1.1800000 1.1650000 1.1500000 1.1350000
#....
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
f <- function(x) {

  nn <- min(n[which( n > x)]) # closed higher value to x in n
  vv <- v[which(n == nn)]     # corresponding value to nn in v

  1.3 - (1.3 - vv) * (x - 10) / (nn - 10)
}
```